# php functions variable scopes

Tags: php

I want to get the variable $place from function getaddress and pass the value to function breakintostrings.  It seems i cant get the variable $place.

```
<?php
   $username ="1224hammer";
  getaddress ($username);
  function getaddress($username)
    {
    $place = row['place'];

     function format_address($record)
      {
      function breakintostrings($x,$y,$z)   

      }  
      breakintostrings($place,"$y","$z") 
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: You're missing a few braces there... also `row` is missing the `$`

Comment: How is this supposed to work anyway?

Comment: Can please explain what you are trying to accomplish overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the variable `$place` outside of your `getaddress` function and import it into your  `breakintostrings`function using the **`global`** keyword:

```
$place = '';

function getaddress($username)
{
   $place = row['place'];
}

function breakintostrings($x,$y,$z)   
  global $place;
  // more code
}
```

Comment: i need $place in breakintostrings

Comment: I want to put $place as the value of $X in breakintostrings

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value by returning the variable $place with the return statement, but please, dont nest your functions. Please

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest your functions like that. Instead, try something like this:

```
function getaddress($username){
    return row['place']; // What is row?
}
function breakintostrings($address,$y,$z){
    // do whatever
}

$address = getaddress($username);
breakintostrings($address,"$y","$z");
```

Comment: :i get u on that. but i'm including lots of files that has made it so

Comment: @karto Including any amount of files shouldn't require you to birds-nest your functions.